# Godot - How can I make a lighting system similar to Terraria

Tags: lighting, godot

I'm making a game similar to Terraria in Godot. I want a lighting system similar to it. The light source is a circle but it still can penetrate through a couple of blocks before stopping. I tried using a Light2D and LightOccluder2D for the blocks but the light just stopped there. How can I make one similar to Terraria.

[Terraria Lighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biFZy.jpg)

This is the same question as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49288411/unity-2d-shader-lighting-like-terraria-or-starbound) but it was in Unity.